# how to set the file's owner for ~ipad.xib?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, ios6.1

I would like to make a universal project that works both on iPhone and iPad.  According to the docs, in order to have a different xib file for the iPad, all I have to do is to create a new xib file and name it with a `~ipad` extension.

```
WhereamiViewController.h 
WhereamiViewController.m   
WhereamiViewController.xib
WhereamiViewController~ipad.xib
```

It works infact. However I need to bind the controls on the new `~ipad.xib` to the same instance variables and methods on `WhereamiViewController.h`.  But how do I achieve this?

How do I set the File's Owner of the new xib to that existing header file?

Comment: Same way you do it in your first `xib`... Click on `File's Owner` > Identity Inspector tab > Custom Class : `WhereamiViewController`.

Comment: ahhh of course. That's it.  If you like to put it as answer, I can tick it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same way you do it in your first `xib`...

Click on **File's Owner** > **Identity Inspector tab** > **Custom Class** : `WhereamiViewController`

Answer (score 0):

I hope your looking to add XIB file for IPad and same .h and .m file  which is already existed for IPhone. check below picture to connect your file's owner [image] once finished according to picture connect your view to file's owner view reference. Then you can give all components reference as you like.

Answer (score 0):

do in this way

File's Owner > Identity Inspector tab > Custom Class : your class name